# Finding a function of a random variable that maximizes some expression

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, optimization

The following problem is part of my studies, so I would prefer hints or suggestions for self-study.

Let $v_1$ be a random variable taking values in $[a,b]$ for $a,b\in \mathbb R$ and assume that the distribution of $v_1$ has density $f_1$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Let $b_1 : [a,b] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a unknown mapping and let $b_2 \in [0,1]$ be a variable. Let $g:[0,1]\times[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a mapping given by:
$$
g(b_1(v_1),b_2) = \Pr (b_1(v_1) \geq b_2) \cdot \mathbb E(v_1 - b_1(v_1))
$$
The problem is then how to find $b_1$ such that $g$ is maximized.

My problem is, that $b_1(v_1)$ is a random variable when $v_1$ is a random variable. Thus I cannot find first-order conditions with respect to $b_1(v_1)$.

I have tried to replace $v_1$ with a non-random variable $x$ taking values in $[0,1]$ and then taking first-order conditions with respect to $x$ and later replacing $v_1$ back again. This gives a result, however $b_1$ becomes constant. Hence it 'loses' it's randomness.

I have read a bit on Radon-Nikodym derivatives but they seems to apply on measures and not random variables. It might be a problem of calculus of variations but my knowledge in this area is very scarce.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: you probably mean
$$
g(b_1(v_1),b_2) = \Pr (b_1(v_1) \geq b_2) \cdot \mathbb E(v_1 - b_1(v_1)).
$$
Also why do you need $v_2$?

Comment: Yes. And I don't need $v_2$. I have edited the post.

Comment: optimizing for a function sounds like Calculus of Variations to me

Comment: Can you recommend a text book for introduction to Calculus of Variations?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Variations-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486414485 and http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Calculus-Variations-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486673669